# 'SB-KERNEL:UNKNOWN-PARSE-TYPE' when connecting Vim to SBCL using Vlime

Tags: vim, common-lisp, sbcl

I have Vim 8.0.1365 with Vlime plugin ([065b95f](https://github.com/l04m33/vlime/commit/065b95f3ac7a455314c2bdefeb2b792f290034df)) installed and an SBCL (1.2.11) session with the start-vlime.lisp loaded, running on macOS 10.14.6 (18G87).

When I connect from Vim using `\cc`, the SBCL session shows `vlime-sbcl - New connection from #<AIO-SBCL:AIO-FD {10048DFD63}` (so the connection works) but then the debugger is invoked with an `SB-KERNEL:PARSE-UNKNOWN-TYPE` condition signalled.

The debugger restarts are:

```
0: [REMOVE-FD-HANDLER] Remove #<SB-IMPL::HANDLER INPUT on descriptor 6: #<FUNCTION AIO-SBCL::SOCKET-INPUT-CB>>
1: [ABORT            ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(VLIME-SBCL::SOCKET-ERROR-CB #<unavailable argument> #<SB-KERNEL:PARSE-UNKNOWN-TYPE {1004BE9B23}>)
```

I've tried both restart options. Removing the handler gives no response, and aborting returns SBCL to the * prompt.

The connection appears to exist in Vim (though there is no success message) and can be selected when using the `\ss` command (I tested on `(+ 3 3)`).

The SWANK window just displays a `--` for each use of `\ss` and an error message below shows:

```
Error detected while processing function vlime#plugin#SendToREPL[100]..vlime#ui#input#MaybeInput[33]..<SNR>42_CheckInputValidity[2]..<SNR>32_SendToREPLInputComplete:
line 2:
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: ListenerEval, [a:content, function('s:OnListenerEvalComplete')]))
E116: Invalid arguments for function(a:conn.ListenerEval, [a:content, function('s:OnListenerEvalComplete')]))
E116: Invalid arguments for function vlime#WithThread
```

I don't have much experience with SBCL or Lisp - this is basically a hurdle at the starting line.

What does the first restart option mean?

The PARSE-UNKNOWN-TYPE condition seems uncommon from a Google search, and not at all in relation to Vlime. What are some next steps I can take to work this out?

Comment: This one is hard to test for me (Vi/vlime, MacOs ...) but maybe try to add the version numbers of the software being involved. A common source of error when dealing with client/server protocols is a mismatch in versions for the different parts involved. The gihub page for vlime lists dependencies and supported implementations, I'd start from there. Also, try starting sbcl in a standalone terminal (first install quicklisp, use "rlwrap sbcl" for readline support) and then load Swank manually, `(ql:quickload :swank)`, and create a server with `(swank:create-server :port 4005)`.

Comment: Ah, SBCL version is too low... strange, I thought I had the most recent! Will fix that and see what happens.

Comment: @coredump, the SBCL version was wrong. I had assumed that the Mac binary available on the SBCL site was the latest. Compiled from source and everything is working smoothly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - can you add this as an answer?

Comment: Nice to see it solved, happy Lisping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posting the comment as an answer)

A common source of error when dealing with client/server protocols is a mismatch in versions for the different parts involved. The [gihub page for vlime](https://github.com/l04m33/vlime) lists dependencies and supported implementations, I'd start from there.

Also, try starting sbcl in a standalone terminal (first install quicklisp, use "rlwrap sbcl" for readline support) and then load Swank manually:

```
(ql:quickload :swank)
```

Create a server

```
(swank:create-server :port 4005)
```

And connect to it, so you can still debug errors from the terminal if there are problems with the client/server interface.